# What is the difference between the many words for "number"?

Tags: word-difference

There are many words in Esperanto to describe a number:

- Nombro
- Kvanto
- Numero
- Grando
- Cifero

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between *nombro* and *numero* is that *nombro* refers to the number itself, as a concept, while *numero* refers purely to a label.

> *Ŝi havas grandan **nombron da** ekzemploj.* She has a large number of examples.
>
> *Ŝi scias la **nombron de** vizitintoj.* She knows the number of visitors [i.e. how many they had].

Note the distinction between *da* and *de*. By contrast, *numero* can only be followed by *de*:

> *Ŝi scias la **numeron de** la domo.* She knows the number of the house.

As for the other words:

- *amplekso* — size, extent, magnitude
- *cifero* — digit, numeral symbol
- *grando* — bigness, size
- *kvanto* — quantity, amount

> *La amplekso de lia agado surprizis min.* The extent of his activity surprised me.
>
> *La horloĝo portis romanajn ciferojn.* The clock bore Roman numerals.
>
> *Tiu simbolo signifas skalaran grandon.* That symbol denotes a scalar quantity [magnitude].
>
> *Mi notis zorge la grandon de la kolekto.* I carefully wrote down the size of the collection.
>
> *Ili havis menciindan kvanton da vino.* They had enough wine to be worth mentioning.

Comment: The word "cifero" is any single symbol used for writing numbers. So most commonly, "cifero" means "digit". But it can also refer to one of the letters used for writing Roman numerals. In English, however, "numeral" usually means the collection of symbols used to denote a number, rather than one of the symbols. For example, in the Wikipedia it say: 'a "j" has sometimes been substituted for the final "i" of a "lower-case" Roman numeral'. Here you couldn't use "cifero" for "numeral", as "numeral" refers to an expression consisting of multiple symbols.

Comment: Mi ne komprenas kial vi skribis nombro de vizitintoj anstataŭ nombro da vizitintoj

Comment: Ekzakte. Ĝi devas "la nombro DA vizintoj" se 'nombro' estas kvanto de io. Se jes, tio ĝi sonas tro simila al 'kvanto' laŭ mi.

Answer (score 1):

- **Nombro**: Number of objects or quantity of something - I have 5 pounds of cheese.
- **Kvanto**: Quantity - I have a large quantity of cheese.
- **Numero**: A regular number - What is the phone number of the cheese company?
- **Grando**: Large - I have a large amount of cheese.
- **Cifero**: Digit - How many digits are in a phone number.

The only difference between Esperanto and English in this regard is between **Nombro** (number to describe quantity) and **Numero** (actual number)

Comment: It is wrong to describe the meaning of "numero" as "mathematical number". A mathematical number is "nombro" in Esperanto. For example, you would say "ℕ estas la aro de naturaj nombroj". The word "numero" is only used for "number" when the number is just a code, i.e. just a sequence of digits that bear no relationship to the quantity or mathematical number that can be referred to with the same sequence of digits.

Comment: Do, kio estas la diferencon inter Nombro kaj Kvanto? Ili ambaŭ ŝajnas esti la sama.